# Anaconda failed installation with ZSH terminal

Tags: anaconda, zsh

Recently I updated my MacBook to Catalina, which has created two problems that as a beginner to programming I'm struggling to resolve:

1. Upon opening terminal, I always get the message:

Last login: Fri Feb 14 00:09:29 on ttys000
/Users/willfletcher/.zshrc:1: permission denied: /Users/willfletcher/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
/Users/willfletcher/.zshrc:2: command not found: conda
(base) willfletcher@Wills-MacBook-Air ~ %

This occurred after I switched to ZSH, which terminal prompted me to do. Also, ZSH doesn't recognise any "Conda" prompts either, which used to work in bash but perhaps there is something missing in my directory somewhere.

2. I uninstalled Anaconda, wiping it clean using the instructions provided on https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/ then tried re-installing it but the installation fails.

How do I resolve these two problems? In Layman's terms please!

Thank you,

Will

Comment: Pehaps `conda` is not there in your `PATH`?  You can use 'which' or 'whereis' command to get the path of 'conda' and check if it is in your 'PATH'. As for the `permission denied` issue, become superuser,  and then try to `chown` the `.zshrc` file for your username (willfletcher).